# lightweight c/c physics engine for school project

Tags: c++, c, macos, animation, physics-engine

I am working on an school **openGl** project, a simple car driving animation. 
I need to a physics c/c++ engine for it.
It needs to be:

1. **lightweight**. It will be only a small piece of my project, not need to be very comprehensive. only need to be provide collision and other basic simulation.
2. **no need to install.**  The project will be compiled and run on school MAC machine, which I can't install anything on it.
3. **XCode/MAC**. I work on xcode. It'd be a framework file or source code that I can use directly.
4. **Written in C/C++**

I tried ODE and Bullet. They are very good, but too much for my project(need to install).

Any suggestion? Thank you very much.